# subtracting data from columns in bash csv

Tags: bash

I have several columns in a file. I want to subtract two columns...

They have these form...without decimals...

```
1.000   900
1.012   1.010
1.015   1.005
1.020   1.010
```

I need another column in the same file with the subtract

```
100
  2
 10
 10
```

I have tried

```
awk - F "," '{$16=$4-$2; print $1","$2","$3","$4","$5","$6}'
```

but it gives me...

```
0.100
0.002 
0.010
0.010
```

Any indication?

Answer (score 1):

Using this `awk`:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '{p=$1;q=$2;sub(/\./, "", p); sub(/\./, "", q); print $0, (p-q)}' file
1.000   900 100
1.012   1.010   2
1.015   1.005   10
1.020   1.010   10
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `perl`:

```
perl -lanE '$,="\t",($x,$y)=map{s/\.//r}@F;say@F,$x-$y' file
```

prints:

```
1.000   900 100
1.012   1.010   2
1.015   1.005   10
1.020   1.010   10
```